# JavaFX show HTML source for WebView control

Tags: java, browser, webview, webkit, javafx

I am putting together a browse in JavaFX using the WebView control. Everything is perfect so far, except I don't know how to implement the 'View Page Source' feature, just like in all major browsers, to display the HTML source of the current page. I have ideas, but they would require some doing. I'm hoping there is a quick way given the fact that WebView uses the WebKit engine just like Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

A

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own [URLStreamHandlerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29) using this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/) as a guide and cache the incoming documents for later display via a view source function.

To allow for a more straightforward implementation (e.g. a webView.getEngine().getSourceText(), or something like that), you will need to file a [jira feature request](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

As an aside, I implemented a [browser](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/) for WebView, which you can adopt stuff from if you wish (it doesn't implement view source at the moment though).

Comment: Thanks! At the moment I'm working on something like this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2401219), but I will try your idea next.

I know your browser... I have studied the code very closely. It's a little too much for my needs as I am doing something very simple and very custom for a client. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the ideas from that link should provide you a good direction and set of alternatives to accomplish this.